# AndroidPlot: Missing Range Origin Label

Tags: androidplot

I have an issue with my graph, when I plot my data, the Range Origin Label is not showing. That is, the first label on the Y-axis is not displayed. I have set my Range step to be:

```
plotView.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 10);
```

However, it only shows 9 labels.

How do I make sure that the range origin label is set?

I have already tried the following:

```
widget.getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
widget.getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

`plotView.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);`.

```
plotView.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

and

```
plotView.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```

are doing this:

[image]

Notice the red range labels and the blue origin line.

As for `plotView.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 10);`, it's dividing your plotview in 10 parts, including the origin.

I'm using `plotView.setRangeStepValue(10);`. Does the same thing, but with simpler syntax.

### UPDATE:

To add a label under the origin labels you have to add first a border style (SQUARE or ROUND):

```
plotView.setBorderStyle(Plot.BorderStyle.SQUARE, null, null);
```

Then:

```
plotView.setDomainLabel("Samples");
plotView.getDomainLabelWidget().pack();
plotView.position(
            plotView.getDomainLabelWidget(),                     
                0,                                    
                XLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_CENTER,       
                0,                                     
                YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,     
                AnchorPosition.BOTTOM_MIDDLE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cannot believe I missed that, I thought I had tried everything ;).

Now, do you know how I can easily write something horizontally centered below the domain labels?

Comment: @SimonLanghoff I've updated my answer with what you've asked.